# Stackoverflow reputation counter bug

Tags: support, reputation

I just happen to realize that there might be bug in reputation counter of SO. In the matter of second, I saw my reputation drop by 20 points for absolutely no reason. Has anyone experienced similar problem? So funny, am I going crazy due to office-work or is it really a bug? I still can't believe it.

Comment: Wild guess, but the first thing that comes to mind would be if two people un-up-voted something.

Comment: Go to the reputation tab, check the "show removed posts" box at the bottom, and see if any deleted posts show up in your history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was recently deleted:

[How do I become faster at programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012062/how-do-i-become-faster-at-programming) (10k only)

You had an answer with two upvotes on it. That reputation is lost when your answer (or the question it was attached to) is deleted.

You can see that in your profile by checking the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of the Reputation tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), and make sure it tallies, and even trigger a recount, at the very bottom.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that :) Nice overview.

Comment: The recalculation button there is no longer useful. All reputation is automatically recalculated at all times. The only thing that might be inaccurate is deleted content, which is accounted for within a few minutes of it occurring. Most everything you can find in that list can be found in your reputation history tab on your profile, in more detail.

Comment: Just curious: What's the first column? The type of action I got/lost rep for?

Comment: @Bergi: Yes. `1` is accepted (2 for accepting an answer, 15 for an answer that got accepted), `2` is an upvote (5 for questions, 10 for answers), `3` is a downvote. I don't know the rest of them, but they go up through like 16 or something.